# How to add text to a Toplevel window

Tags: python, text, tkinter, toplevel

I want to add text to the windows that opening when I click the "x" and "x1" buttons. But I couldn't figure it out.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

def create_window():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))


b = tk.Button(root, text="x", command=create_window)
b.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

b1 = tk.Button(root, text="x1", command=create_window)
b1.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use a `Label` widget.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please show me a little example?

Comment: There are millions of examples on the internet of using label widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Bryan means something like this:

```
def create_window():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    tk.Label(window, text='your text').pack(padx=30, pady=30)
```

And as he said read some examples before posting. It looks like you don't know what Toplevel is....

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am new in Python. I searched a lot of website but I couldn't find something like you just wrote.

Comment: a Toplevel window is a window that appears over the root window. So you have to put widgets (labels, buttons and others) on it to see something

Comment: Thanks again! Finally I created the program that I need after you help me.